# ColdFusion 10 suddenly not loading

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I came home from work tonight to do some development but I noticed that my application wasn't loading so then tried to access the CF administrator but this also won't load.

I've checked and all ColdFusion services say they are running and I've even uninstalled and re-installed CF10 but with no luck!

The colfusion-error log has the following in it:

```
Jul 01, 2013 9:31:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\\ColdFusion10\\cfusion\lib;C:\\ColdFusion10\\cfusion\jintegra\bin;C:\\ColdFusion10\\cfusion\jintegra\bin\international;C:\\ColdFusion10\\cfusion\lib\oosdk\classes\win
Jul 01, 2013 9:32:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8500"]
Jul 01, 2013 9:32:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8012"]
Jul 01, 2013 9:32:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 01, 2013 9:32:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.23
Jul 01, 2013 9:35:12 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [188,567] milliseconds.
Jul 01, 2013 9:35:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ColdFusionStartUpServlet: ColdFusion: Starting application services
Jul 01, 2013 9:35:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ColdFusionStartUpServlet: ColdFusion: VM version = 23.7-b01
```

And the coldfusion-out log has the following:

```
01/07 21:35:29 INFO License Service: Flex 1.5 CF Edition enabled
01/07 21:35:29 INFO Starting Flex 1.5 CF Edition
Jul 1, 2013 21:35:30 PM Information [pool-2-thread-1] - Starting logging...
Jul 1, 2013 21:35:30 PM Information [pool-2-thread-1] - Starting license...
```

My last Java update was on 20/07 so it's nothing to do with that and I don't know of anything else that will have changed since yesterday.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What're they doing instead of loading? Just sitting there and spinning, or erroring? Anything in the application or exception logs? Also, are you hitting your site & CFAdmin via an external web server (eg: Apache, IIS), or via the inbuilt web server? If the former, what happens if you *do* use the internal web server?

Comment: What are you running on? OSX, Windows or Linux? Do you have automatic system updates (patches and such) set?

Comment: Just sitting there and spinning - not even timing out and there's nothing in the application or exception logs. Also using the internal web server on Windows 8 with automatic updates not sent. Honestly completely stumped by this! :(

Comment: what url are you using to access the CF instance? localhost:8500 ought to be the safest to use, rather than involving machine name or anything else which may be work-related. Have you worked from home ok before? Also, Windows Firewall can (I think) have different rules set up for different kinds of networks, so you may have port 8500 allowed inbound on the work network but not your home one?

Comment: 127.0.0.1:8500 although tried localhost:8500 as well. Everything was working fine the evening before then the following evening this started happening! :-\